# Problem with stream maptostream average if all elements are null

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, average

I have a problem with the following line, it goes directly to exception if all the values are null, shouldn't it return 0?

```
Double avgTemperature = temp.stream()
       .filter(o -> o != null)
       .mapToDouble(EnvironmentData::getTemperature)
       .average()
       .getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAsDouble()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` if the `OptionalDouble` is empty.

Use `orElse` in order to specify a default value:

```
double avgTemperature = temp.stream().filter(o -> o != null).mapToDouble(EnvironmentData::getTemperature).average().orElse(0.0);
```

Note that if `getTemperature()` returns a reference type, and it might return `null`, you should filter out these `null` values too:

```
double avgTemperature = 
    temp.stream()
        .filter(o -> o != null && o.getTemperature() != null)
        .mapToDouble(EnvironmentData::getTemperature)
        .average()
        .orElse(0.0);
```